# Error while deploying this repo in AWS(timdettmers/guanaco-33b-merged LLM)

Tags: python, aws-lambda, amazon-sagemaker, large-language-model

so I'm using AWS Sagemaker to host this model (timdettmers/guanaco-33b-merged ), and then using AWS lambda to host this model in a serverless architecture and API gateway, which acts as a trigger to the lambda function. After hosting the model in Sagemaker. I cloned this repo to my local computer. and changed the API_URL in the app.py to the endpoint where the model is AWS SAGEMAKER and ran the file. I encountered the following error. [Code Snippet] [https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXXzV.png]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXXzV.png%5D) https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOifR.png https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rOV6.png https://i.stack.imgur.com/5TCEQ.png

Please help me resolve this issue.your text Thanks in advance!your text your text Want to run this model.
Iam able to deploy the model but not able to run it. Facing issues.

Comment: Which repo are you cloning? Are you able to invoke the model from a SageMaker notebook (without the API gw/Lambda) architecture?